# rails capture timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am liking a rails app to Xero accounting. When creating an invoice, the first thing I have to do is go and look for the contact against whom the invoice will be stored. the code for this is simple enough, being..

```
private_app = XeroGatewayProvider.new.create_private_app    
contact_response = private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345")
```

where "12345" is the unique ID in Xero accounts. Now, I just know that sooner later the contact will be missing from xero, or for whatever reason it won't be able to find it so I want to code around that and stop the code from trying to create an invoice for a contact that does not exist. Now if I run the code with a missing ID it actually crashed out with an error, as in

```
XeroGateway::ObjectNotFound (Couldn't find object for API Endpoint https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts/12345?contactID=12345):
  app/controllers/saas_admin/hr_partners_controller.rb:102:in `send_to_xero'
```

clearly, I can't have the app crashing out, so I borrowed some code from elsewhere in the app that catches errors, which is this...

```
  def exception_catcher
    begin
      yield
    rescue Exception => err
      # puts "\nException in saas billing: \n#{err.message}\n\t#{err.backtrace.join("\n\t")}\n"
      Rails.logger.error("\nException in saas billing: \n#{err.message}\n\t#{err.backtrace.join("\n\t")}\n")
    end
  end
```

so now the code becomes

```
# catch errors
 def exception_catcher
   begin
     yield
   rescue Exception => err
     # puts "\nException in saas billing: \n#{err.message}\n\t#{err.backtrace.join("\n\t")}\n"
     Rails.logger.error("\nException in saas billing: \n#{err.message}\n\t#{err.backtrace.join("\n\t")}\n")
   end
 end

# fetch person record
private_app = XeroGatewayProvider.new.create_private_app    
exception_catcher do
  contact_response = private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345")
end
```

OK, so far so good, the code now executes, and if it doesn't find a person it carries on without crashing the app. Here is the problem. what I want to do is stop the app from carrying on with trying to create an invoice if there is no contact response. So something like

```
unless contact_response.nil
  go off and create an invoice
end
```

The problem is that contact_response doesn't actually exist if it errors. I've tried putting in a rescue such as

```
contact_response = private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345")  rescue nil
```

I've also tried checking if contact_response is present or defined, but it always reports back that

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `contact_response'
```

help!

EDIT:

Ok, this works, is it a sensible solution...

```
unless (defined?(contact_response)).nil?
  go off and create the invoice
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the code dependent on contact_response into the catched block

```
exception_catcher do
  contact_response = private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345")
  create_invoice(contact_response)
end
```

But be careful. Why are you doing this pokemon exception handling. Shouldn't you just catch the `XeroGateway::ObjectNotFound` Exception

```
begin 
  contact_response = private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345")
  create_invoice(contact_response)
rescue XeroGateway::ObjectNotFound => err
  #log stuff 
end
```

Also checking for defined var is somewhat ugly. If you can't change the code having only the exception handling as a single check, just initialize the vars with nil.

```
contact_response = nil
exception_catcher do ... end
if contact_response
  ...
end
```

And if your app should not execute some code after this exception occurs, just don't catch it at all and let this request crash. Configure rails, showing some general error, if that happens

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose it:

```
contact_response = (private_app.get_contact_by_id("12345") rescue nil)
```